# Declare a new array in JavaScript with a var as its size

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

totally new to JS but need to use it atm.

In C language I can declare new arrays the following way: `int A[10], B[A];`

This way I can create custom sized arrays of a variable.

Is it possible to do the same with JavaScript? I need to make an Array with the size of a variable.
I tried to do stuff like: `var n = 10; var A = new Array(n);` but it just doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? `new Array(n)` will definitely create you an array with `n` slots.

Comment: There's little point in doing that in JavaScript, as arrays are quite different than they are in C. An array created with `new Array(10)` can hold 100 or 1000 elements.

Comment: What @Pointy says is also correct - usually pre-allocating an array is more or less useless. Arrays are a bit of a misnomer, in JavaScript they are dynamically allocated. Having a pre-allocated size is only useful in a handfull of cases that are on the edge side of things. A code that creates an array of given size isn't exactly wrong but usually it doesn't need to do that.

Comment: @Pointy, i'm curious, what is the utility of that ? (Seems to be not logic)

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://wandbox.org/permlink/oxtxQIuINnioo5xz

Comment: @Eng that's just how arrays work in JavaScript. The behavior of arrays may have been different 20 or more years ago, and pre-allocating *might* have been a good idea, but those days are (for the most part) gone.

Comment: @Pointy _"pre-allocating might have been a good idea, but those days are gone."_ No, they're definitely not gone. Pre-allocating is much faster than reallocating. Reallocating could involve a copy of all elements.

Comment: @ThomasSablik but we don't have statically sized or even typed arrays (speaking of the basic array, that is). Some environments will try to match your data and give you a decent array representation but they don't have to. There is nothing in the specs that require this and making arrays static will break legacy code.

Comment: @ThomasSablik what I meant was that the way modern JavaScript runtimes work is largely opaque to the programmer, and the rate of change in optimization strategies is so high that trying to "game" the runtimes is for most applications not worth the trouble.

Comment: @VLAZ I'm not talking about arrays with static size. But it's faster to preallocate an array and fill it than to fill an empty array. At the end JavaScript is just calling C functions to allocate memory and that's expensive.

Comment: @Maggiorana I see you want an array of ints, check out `var A = new Int32Array(10)` and [its friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray#typedarray_objects)

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
Array(n)
```

or

```
Array.from({length: n})  // Creates array from array-like or iterable.
```

But it's still possible to push new items.

```
let arr = Array(5)  // [empty x 5]
arr[25] = 10        // [empty x 25, 10]
```

Performance-wise `Array(n).fill()` suggested by @Thomas is much faster than `Array.from({length: n})`.

Measurements:

```
Array(500)                  // 0.009999959729611874. But it's sparse.
Array.from({length: 500})   // 0.0850000069476664
Array(500).fill(undefined)  // 0.01999997766688466
```

Comment: `Array.from()` is slow because it has to be so flexible about the passed argument, but at least the returned Array is not sparse. But `Array(n).fill()` is in my opinion still better.

Comment: Thanks, added to the answer.